# Nested data on api response are coming as null in Nextjs 13

Tags: javascript, next.js, apollo-client, apollo-server, next.js13

I have a graphql server.
I am using @apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/rsc for registering my apollo client on server and @apollo/client.
Now, I am loading an array of objects from my graphql server.
The data is like this
`users = [{id:"", name:"", doctor:{bio:"", speciality:""}}]`
I am loading this data on a server component. Now the issue is on my client components and my console I am getting this,
`users = [{id:"", name:"", doctor:null}]` 
I don't know why this happening. For testing if I convert the data into string using JSON.stringify and then console it I can even see my doctor object inside my user object.
What can be the issue?

This is the code that I am using on my sever component for get the user from apollo client,

```
  const { data:DoctorsDataForSlider }:{
    data:DoctorsForHomePageQuery | undefined
  } = await getClient().query({ query: DoctorsForHomePageDocument , variables:doctorQueryVariables});
```

As you can see in the screenshot. The first data is showing doctor where I used json.stringify and on the second data doctor is null where I used the parsed data.

#### Current vs. Expected behavior

Nested object on api response set as null.
I should get my full API response data.

#### Verify canary release

- [X] I verified that the issue exists in the latest Next.js canary release

#### Provide environment information

```bash
Platform: Macos
Package Manager:  pnpm
Nodejs:v18.16.0
Nextjs:13.4.19
```

#### Which area(s) are affected? (Select all that apply)

App Router, CLI (create-next-app), Data fetching (gS(S)P, getInitialProps)

#### Additional context

*No response*

nextjs 13 canary rease

Comment: on my registerApolloClient I was using cache as a result it was not loading my updated server data. I just used fetchOptions: { cache: "no-store" }. which resolved my issue.